# Optimization of numpy array traversal

Tags: python, performance, numpy, optimization, multidimensional-array

**1.** Consider the following traversal of a **numpy.ndarray**

```
for ii in xrange(0,(nxTes-2)):
    if ( (xCom-dtaCri-xcTes[ii]) * (xCom-dtaCri-xcTes[ii+1]) ) <= 0.0:
        nxL=ii
    if ( (xCom+dtaCri-xcTes[ii]) * (xCom+dtaCri-xcTes[ii+1]) ) <= 0.0:
        nxR=ii+1
```

**2.** `xCom`, `dtaCri` and `xcTes` are of type() **numpy.float64**, **float** and **numpy.ndarray** respectively

**3.** The full block above is repeated for `nyTes` and `nzTes` i.e. a total of three blocks are done in the main algorithm loop. The goal is to create a region of interest with window size `dtaCri` and center at comparison point `xCom` using positional data from `xcTes`

**4.** The above code is more or less a straight port from Matlab wherein the same block executes at somewhere around three to four times the speed.

**5. Question:** Is it possible to optimize the block above with respect to execution time and if so how?

**6.** So far I have tried some minor tweaks such as altering data types and using **range()** instead of **xrange()** from which I saw no noticeable changes in performance.

Comment: MATLAB is probably faster because it is doing some form of jit compilation.  That lets you think iteratively.  `numpy` is more like old MATLAB where you had to focus on whole-matrix operations.  Can you write that in MATLAB without the iteration? (with masks and so on)?

Comment: Agreed. And no, I am not sure there is a "simple" way of rewriting the Matlab code. Atleast not at present. I will instead spend some time trying to perfect the Python interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre-compute those boolean conditional outputs before going into the loop in a vectorized manner and making use of slicing, which are just views into the input array, like so -

```
parte1 = ( (xCom-dtaCri-xcTes[:nxTes-2]) * (xCom-dtaCri-xcTes[1:nxTes-1]) ) <=0.0
parte2 = ( (xCom+dtaCri-xcTes[:nxTes-2]) * (xCom+dtaCri-xcTes[1:nxTes-1]) ) <=0.0
```

We could see few computations are repeated. So, we could use some re-use there -

```
p = xCom-xcTes[:nxTes-1]
p0 = p - dtaCri
p1 = p + dtaCri
parte1 = p0[:-1]*p0[1:] <= 0.0
parte2 = p1[:-1]*p1[1:] <= 0.0
```

Then, just use those bools in the loop -

```
for ii in xrange(0,(nxTes-2)):
    if parte1[ii]:
        nxL=ii
    if parte2[ii]:
        nxR=ii+1
```

The idea is to do minimal work inside the loop with focus on performance.

I am assuming you have more work going in the loop that is using `nxL` and `nxR`, because otherwise we are overwriting values into those two variables.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, there are several more sections happening later in the algorithm that depend on the region of interest generated from the above segment. I will try to implement your suggestion and report back with results.

Comment: Very interesting result: I am processing medical images and the old method takes ~2.34s per processed layer (i.e. roughly 2½s per x, y or z)

New method, where one major change is making use of slicing, takes ~0.49s

Net result: ~4.8 times performance increase.

Seems xmas came early this year. Thank you.

Comment: @Peter That's not bad, is it! Awesome, have a great holiday!

Comment: You're still doing ~2x the work generating `parte1` and `parte2`, since most values are duplicated between the arrays.

Comment: @Veedrac Good point, thanks! Updated with those improvements.

Comment: @Peter Check out some possible improvements in the edited codes!

Comment: @Divakar I meant more like `parte = xCom - xcTes[:nxTes-1]; parte1 = parte - dtaCri; parte1 = (parte1[:-1] * parte1[1:]) <= 0; parte2 = parte + dtaCri; parte2 = (parte2[:-1] * parte2[1:]) <= 0`.

Comment: @Veedrac Ah yes, computing differences for `:n-1` and slicing to re-use, good trick, thanks! Updated.

Comment: @Peter I see, thanks for reporting back nevertheless!

Comment: @Veedrac and divakar New code shows no significant improvement in performance. If anything this new setup is slightly (tens of microseconds) slower. But since I only ran like five rounds of tests thats not really all that conclusive.

Comment: Not as to drag this comment section out forever but I just had to get a better understanding of what was going on in this new suggestion. I felt it SHOULD be somewhat faster (and a bit more than what I saw initially) so I did one more round of analysis and can now report a performance increase of ~3.8819% relative to previous method. With this new insight I have decided to go with the updated method, espec. since these sections of the algo are used frequently. Thank you once again!